# How to sum rows of a column with same key in a different column of the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

```
  df = prem[['HomeTeam','HP','AP']]
  print(df)
             HomeTeam  HP  AP
  0         Liverpool   3   0
  1          West Ham   0   3
  2       Bournemouth   1   1
  3           Burnley   3   0
  4    Crystal Palace   1   1
  ..              ...  ..  ..
  283          Wolves   1   1
  284         Burnley   1   1
  285         Chelsea   3   0
  286      Man United   3   0
  287       Leicester   3   0
```

I am wondering how I would sum all of the home points for West Ham. All I can come up with is the sum of the whole HP, home points, column.

Comment: do you want `df.groupby('HomeTeam')['HP'].sum()`

Comment: No not exactly that but the total sum of HP for West Ham when they're the home team

Comment: `df.loc[df['HomeTeam'] == 'West Ham'], 'HP'].sum()` then I think.

Answer (score 0):

From what is being asked, i would guess then it is:

```
df.loc[df['HomeTeam'] == 'West Ham'], 'HP'].sum()
```